# How do I set Spring/Gradle project class path to pick up configuration XML file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a simple Spring,Gradle-based web service project with the following
structure:

```
UserSettingController
  src/main/java
    com.ui.usersetting.datamodel
    com.ui.usersetting.restinterface
    com.ui.usersetting.UserSettingController
  resources
    resources_deployment1
       spring-resource1.xml
    resources_deployment2
    ...
```

There is an @Autowired JdbcTemplate variable in `com.ui.usersetting.datamodel`
for which the definition appears in `resource/resources_deployment1/spring-resource1.xml`.
There is also in `com.ui.usersetting.datamodel` a @Configuration file containing
`@ImportResource("classpath:spring-resource1.xml")`.

This builds and deploys OK, but when I hit one of the endpoints defined in
`com.ui.usersetting.restinterface`, I get the following error from Spring:

```
class path resource [spring-resource1.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I assume that this means that `UserSettingController/resources/resources_deployment1/`,
which contains `spring-resource1.xml`, does not appear on the class path.  I've tried
to fix this by setting the class path in Eclipse, but since I build using Gradle 
command-line commands rather than Eclipse, this fix doesn't work.

I need to maintain the structure above, rather than moving `spring-resource1.xml`
to `src/main/resources`, to be consistent with other projects in our group.  So,
how can I get Spring to look in the right place for `spring-resourc1.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add extra `resources` folders to your `sourceSets`. Assuming you have for instance 3 `resources_deployment` folders :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            (1..3).each {
                srcDir "resources/resources_deployment$it"
            }
        }
    }
}
```